# There is nohup, is there a nousr1 command?

Tags: linux

Several of my regular programs crash (on a regular basis) with the message "User defined signal 1".  I know there is a `nohup` command, but is there a `nousr1` command?  Or something which will do something like `nohup` but with USR1?

Comment: The better question might be what is sending it the usr1 signal in the first place?  If nothing is, the exit message may simply be misleading.

Comment: Sounds like you might have some serious problems in your "regular programs" ... simply disabling signals may not correct or enable the underlying applications to properly function.  I'd strongly suggest that you examine your environment CAREFULLY before just disabling things.

Comment: @Grant: I agree. Is there a utility which can tell me what is sending these signals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple hacky solution to have the utility analogous to `nohup`, but for `SIGUSR1`, would be to get a copy of [coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) source, unpack it, do

```
sed -i 's/SIGHUP/SIGUSR1/' /path/to/coreutils/src/nohup.c
```

, optionally also change the output file name

```
sed -i 's/nohup\.out/nousr1.out/g' /path/to/coreutils/src/nohup.c
```

, compile this source and install the newly-compiled `nohup` binary to `/usr/bin/nousr1`:

```
cp /path/to/coreutils/src/nohup /usr/bin/nousr1
```

After this, as I checked, `sleep 1000` exits on `USR1`, while `nousr1 sleep 1000` is immune to this signal.

Comment: The main functionality of `nohup`, by the way, is to disassociate the process from the terminal so it isn't sent `SIGHUP` in the first place. That it also sets up a signal handler is an additional bonus, but should be unnecessary.

Comment: @SimonRichter If you remove the `signal(SIGHUP,SIG_IGN);` call in `nohup.c`, the process will receive the `SIGHUP`. What `nohup` does aside from ignoring the signal is just reopening the stdin,stdout,stderr descriptors as non-terminal files. It doesn't really disassociate the process from the terminal in any special way. I.e., the process will be sent `SIGHUP` when terminal hangs up. On the other side there's bash, which does similar thing with `disown` command, but I'm not sure how _it_ is implemented — maybe in the way you mean.

Comment: This seems to work well.

Answer (score 8):

How about the shell [`trap`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-trap) built-in command?

```
trap 'echo "Thou shalt not USR1 me"' USR1
```

Comment: Good idea, but it didn't work. The process exited anyway with "User defined signal 1".

Comment: Signal handlers (other than SIG_IGN and SIG_DFL) are *not* inherited by child processes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the form of the `trap` command with a blank argument. Try this:

```
trap '' SIGUSR1; myprogram
```

This will *ignore* the SIGUSR1 signal which is what you're trying to do. Although I agree with the commenters that there is probably more going on here than meets the eye.

The incorrect form:

```
trap 'echo ...' SIGUSR1; myprogram
```

will still allow `myprogram` to receive the SIGUSR1 but the shell will then execute the `echo` from the `trap` command.

Comment: This seems to work well.

Comment: Oops, I spoke too soon.  I was running `trap '' SIGUSR1; gvimdiff file1 file2` and Vim died with "Vim: Caught deadly signal USR1".

Comment: Hmmm, looking at the source-code at http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/os_unix.c it seems that VIM re-enables the USR1 signal and treats it as a fatal error.  Your only hope would seem to be if you can make the OS refuse to deliver the USR1 signal.  I don't know if there is something out there that can provide that functionality.

Comment: More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4515274/41861

Comment: Adrian Pronk: it's not just Vim; it's also Firefox, and Aqualung, and Thunderbird, and some others.  But not other apps, such as Konsole, which runs forever.